# Count on rows based on another rows in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count rows in Python's Panda based on another rows.

Below is data source.
[image]

And below is what I want.
[image]

But it cannot achieved using `df.groupby(['bug']).count()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
pd.crosstab(df.module, df.bug)
```